# Is it possible to explicitly to refer to indexes by their name in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, indexing, dataframe, pandas

In pandas DataFrames allow a combination of columns to build an index (if every row has a unique combination of values from these columns). One of the benefits of doing that is simplification of the syntax, rather than:

```
my_data_frame[(my_data_frame['column_name_1']==0) & (my_data_frame['column_name_2']==1)]
```

We can use:

```
my_data_frame[(0,1)]
```

Here is an example of how I use several columns to build an index:

```
import pandas as pd

ls = [{'col1':10, 'col2':0, 'col3':0, 'col4':100}, {'col1':20, 'col2':0, 'col3':1, 'col4':200}, {'col1':30, 'col2':1, 'col3':0, 'col4':300}, {'col1':40, 'col2':1, 'col3':1, 'col4':400}]    
df = pd.DataFrame(ls).set_index(['col2','col3'])

df.ix[(0,0)]['col1']  # returns 10
df.ix[('col3'=1, 'col2'=0)] # <----- This does not work. (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)
```

Is it possible to do something like given in the last line of the above code? Of course I can do:

```
df[(1, 2, 0, 'aaa', 10)]
```

But for that I always need to remember the *order* of the index. It would be nicer if I can do something like:

```
df[(age=10, scale=2, grade=0, name='aaa', size=1)]
```

Comment: I think the answer is no... but you could write a helper function to do it.

Comment: Pandas improvement to file? I found the sugar you are searching for useful enough to hope it would be built in somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own helper:

```
In [11]: df1
Out[11]:
           col1  col4
col2 col3
0    0       10   100
     1       20   200
1    0       30   300
     1       40   400

In [12]: d = {'col3': 1, 'col2': 0}
```

If you knew for certain you were passing all of the names, you could just put them in the correct order:

```
In [13]: t = tuple(map(d.get, df1.index.names))

In [14]: t
Out[14]: (0, 1)

In [15]: df1.loc[t]
Out[15]:
col1     20
col4    200
Name: (0, 1), dtype: int64
```

If you didn't, and wanted something a little more robust, you could do something a little trickier as follows (there's *surely* a more efficient way to do it though, without reducing). But here's one idea:

```
def reduce_kv(df, kv):
    try:
        return df.xs(kv[1], level=kv[0])
    except (AttributeError,):
        if df.index.name == kv[0]:
            return df.loc[kv[1]]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("Level %s not found" % kv[0])

In [17]: reduce(reduce_kv, d.items(), df1)
Out[17]:
col1     20
col4    200
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

*Note: the name probably also needs changing...*